# Unload a file from a ftp and rename it in host

Tags: mainframe, jcl, zos

I have one file delivered in a ftp daily. This file doesn´t have the same name everyday. It has the date and the hour of the creation. For example, today the file has the name 20130814_XX_YY_20130814152345, created at 15:23:45 and tomorrow the file can name 20130815_XX_YY_20130815152421. The _XX_YY_ is always the same but the hour will change everyday.

I want to create a host jcl that gets this file with variable name and rename it to a host file. How can I do this ?

Thank you
Regards
Chuchito

Comment: @ppeterka, I have no trouble understanding the question, I would think most mainframe programmers would. It would be better if he added mainframe tags

Comment: @BruceMartin Welcome to [SO]. You should also read the [FAQ], this question does not show any efforts. I do have the ability to understand the question - even without being a mainframe programmer. However, I don't like doing people's jobs who don't even _try_ to solve their problem, instead post "I want flying unicorn, gimme teh codez ASAP!". Had the OP posted an "I tried this code, it gave this error" question, would have been my attitude towards the question better. Also, if you feel a tag is appropriate, you can edit the post to add it. Trying does not hurt. Disrespect does.

Comment: @ppeterka, I agree people should make an attempt and I did not mean to offend, but in this case unless you know the solution already, you will not know what to try. Also I did edit the post to add mainframe tags, but these where not accepted

Answer (score 3):

STEP1: You can use LS in FTP to write to disk, so you can have a file with the file-name in it. Then GET that file.

STEP2: Process the contents of your file to generate the FTP Control Cards (at least for the GET). The GET generated will be of the form GET 20130814_XX_YY_20130814152345 'HLQ.MAINFRAM.DATASET', where the server name has come from the file GETted in STEP1 and the local (Mainframe) file can be hard-coded, or supplied to the generation if flexibility is required.

STEP3: Run FTP again with the Control Card(s) generated.

Isn't there anything in the Spec?

Comment: I presume the generated ftp GET command would look something like: `GET 20130814_XX_YY_20130814152345 'HLQ.MAINFRAM.DATASET'` so dataset renaming occurs as part of the tranfer (since the source dataset name as given does not conform to mainframe naming conventions).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we create complexities where an "out of the box" solution simplifies life considerably.

After the post updated, I now understand the problem a bit better.

If the name is required to be so specific, then the other suggested solution (if i understand it) is to have a fixed file name on the server that contains a list of file names to be uploaded.

In fact, the server could create a fixed file name that is really the JCL to run on the mainframe!!!  This file would include the //SYSIN DD * and GET commands!  The mainframe uploads this file and submits it as-is to the job reader, which then runs on the mainframe.  The last step of this job (created by the server, but run on the mainframe) is to FTP an empty JCL file back to the server, in this way the server "knows" that the mainframe has uploaded the files.

Alternatively, why does the non-Z\os system need to name the file with time information? If the mainframe processes the file daily then date should be sufficient.

With this change the mainframe can reliably predict the file name for the day, generate the appropriate GET command and run.

With a job scheduler it would be easy to run the upload to the mainframe twice a day.  This might address any concerns that are expressed in the desire to include a time in the file's name.

Comment: @NealB, have re-reviewed this question and have adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Run a Rexx step via a Background TSO step:

- [Background TSO step](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.ikja300/tsorun.htm)

You can then  run a [listcat](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.ikjc500/listcat.htm) to get all the files. You could either write the listcat output to a file and read it in or trap the output via the Address command
 or the [OutTrap function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r12.ikjc500/listcat.htm).

Then use the standard TSO Rename command.

Alternatively you could run ISPF background rexx program and use the ISPF equivalents to get the file name

Comment: The file which is so named is on a non-Mainframe (or at least non-z/Os) server. What would you rename? The aim is to get the file-name from the server into some Control Cards for FTP.

Comment: My reading is the file is FTP'd to the mainframe and he wants to rename it to a standard Mainframe file (copying to a GDG would be an alternative) for latter processing

Comment: Yes, but it can't "arrive" on the Mainframe with that name. So give it a new name with the GET, which requires the generation of that card, requiring knowledge of the name on the server. Unless I've missed something...

Comment: Bill, you do have a point there with the name, although it could have that name in the Unix subsystem that ZOS comes with these days

Comment: Yes, but you don't want to rename on the server (original file "lost"). Not much point in copying it on the server just to get a new name. Thus, generate the GET I feel. TS is not keeping up like we do anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

(1) The real solution to this should be through a scheduling tool for Mainframe jobs. These tools provide capabilities to take care of formatting like the one you described.

(2) Alternatives: REXX and COBOL

(3) If you don't want to prefer REXX, here's a little brief into how you could create the JCL dynamically using COBOL:

- A COBOL program that would read a "template" JCL.
- Using INSPECT / REPLACE, you could substitute the prototypes with the string that is populated with the date of your choice (you could supply this as a simple SYSIN parm too, if you want the COBOL code to be flexible on the date selection)
- Now that your formatted JCL is ready, you could write it to the output stream

//OUTFILE DD SYSOUT=(INTRDR,*)
or
//OUTFILE DD SYSOUT=(*,INTRDR)

Anything that is written to INTRDR (Internal Reader), goes straight to JES to submit your job!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Control-M is one of several scheduling packages. Please revise your answer to remove specific product references, or add more scheduling packages as examples.

Comment: As well as more than one scheduler package being available, some sites don't allow the use of the INTRDR. Where are you going to get the file-name for your "template" approach anyway?

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr - Thanks, removed the reference. Although, if similar examples could be given, those would be Tivoli and CSAR.

Comment: @BillWoodger - Think I get your point (and my reply would have been similar to Bruce's). There's a lack of a set of rules in this case. However, the essence of the answer was, if names can be derived by following a known convention, then, in the absence of a tool, a programming language such as COBOL can be used to build the JCL dynamically and submitted to INTRDR.
Does that make sense, please? Thanks.